# How to increase the space size of IQ server?

Tags: database, space, sap-iq

Can you please help me on this as I am facing a space issue when we do any sql query on IQ database. Below is the query to increase the space.

```
ALTER DBSPACE IQ_SYSTEM_MAIN ALTER FILE abc_iqdemo ADD  5GB.
```

But I am getting the error which is below

```
Could not execute statement.
Syntax error near '-' on line 1
SQLCODE=-131, ODBC 3 State="42000"
Line 1, column 1
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Many thanks. 
Best regards. 
Jitendra

Comment: Are you sure it's this query? If yes, please replace . with ; for the beginning.

Comment: Yes, Frlan this is the query, but for a change I try with giving "
"  to the file name ALTER DBSPACE IQ_SYSTEM_MAIN ALTER FILE "abc_iqdemo" ADD  5GB. thinking that it might work. But failed.Can you help on this.